# I get an error with almost any AppCompat v21 widget I try to use

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I've just starteda new project and I've been trying for a couple days to make it work with the new Material Design AppCompat (v21) but everytime I try to put a widget like a CardView or the new Toolbar I end up with an error that doesn't let the screen draw them.

For example, this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Returns this error:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.CardView (Open Class, Show Exception)
```

Also, using this code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

Return this error:

```
Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the     layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.  Failed to find style     'toolbarStyle' in current theme (6 similar errors not shown)
```

I have already added AppCompat to Gradle build and I'm using Theme.AppCompat.Light as well as extending from ActionBarActivity.

Am I doing something wrong? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just the layout editor's bug.

Try to run the app to see if there's an actual error.

Comment: Yay, it works! I have no clue that it'll be just a layout editor bug, but it works like charm. Hope Google fixes it soon, though, it's a bit annoying having to execute the app in order to see the design I'm working on.

Comment: Thank you Fauzie. It is still not fixed in Android Studio v1.5!

Comment: not a bug, the correct sintax is:

?android:attr/actionBarSize